# good azure storage client library?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there one? (for .net)

I see msft samples StorageDotNEt and StorageRest. These dont do if-match right and they dont appear to do paged queries

Lokad has a library but does funky stuff to spread data over columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the one that is supported and ships with the SDK?  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll?  This supports blob, table, and queues.  Check the Windows Azure Training Kit for basic manuevers with it.

Comment: my mistake. The base DataServices library does both pagination and if-match. It sjust that the sample renders the if-match useless (it rereads the row before updating)

Answer (score 0):

At a low level I also used the http://azurekit.codeplex.com/ library - not a finished beast but is a more direct mapping of C# to REST - if that's what you need.

Comment: This is also in the aforementioned 'official' SDK client in spades.  Look under Microsoft.Windows.StorageClient.Protocol and you have nothing but the foundational REST calls (HttpWebRequest).  The higher level abstraction is built on this and you can use it directly as well.

Comment: Agreed - but if you do want to be sure of what you're doing, then there's something nice about seeing the source :) Stuart (who uses the official SDK for 99% of his access!)